# Excel - SUM Columns IF column header is EQUAL to while another column header is EQUAL to BUT value is not 0

Tags: excel

I have a table like this:

```
January            February            March                 Year to Date
Actual | Target    Actual | Target     Actual | Target       Actual | Target
100    | 100       50     | 100        0      | 100          150    | 200
```

What I basically want to achieve is for Year to Date to SUM Target if Actual of each month is greater than zero (0).

Can this be achieved via Excel Formulas?

Comment: There is a way to do it. But it would be far simpler if your data was arranged in columns. i.e. Column A is "Month", Column B is "Actual", Column C is "Target" and then you have down the rows each month and their corresponding values and then in the last row you have "Year to Date" as the month. If you're not opposed to that format it's straight forward. If you are opposed I can share a method that works that's less straight forward.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz Sadly, I cannot change the format for it is a requirement that Months be in Row 1 and Actual + Target be in Row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:G3,((A3:F3)>0)*1,(B2:G2="Target")*1)
```

I am assuming that you can use column to the left of your data. If you can't just skip January in the sumproduct and add it with a simple IF.

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much.  Short and smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Aaa +1 to this would be easier if you could re-arrange data.

The [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function is helpful here.
Are you able to use an additional row? If not, is your Target always 100?
Assuming yes to one of these, the below will work. Highlighted cells have highlighted equations.

**To calculate YTD Target**: Green uses extra row `4`, orange assumes target is always the same (100)

[image: Mock solution]

**NB**: the empty column `A` is so that the same equation canbe used in all cells on row `4`. You can get rid of it and the equation in `B4` without anything messing up.

Comment: Good answer.  However, the additional rows of data while helpful might confuse the users of the report.  Better yet, some of the users like to copy and paste rows without care.  This might overwrite the helper rows and will cause miss computations.